# Jet map aggregation performance bottleneck: how do you avoid serialization of local records?

Tags: hazelcast-jet

Summary:
I'm trying to leverage the jet pipeline for high-load aggregation. I'm finding that the overwhelming majority of runtime is taken up by serializing and deserializing my map records through a bytestream (they implement DataSerializable). I thought the point of distributing the aggregation operation to the nodes was that they had direct access to the distributed members in the heap.

Pipeline:

```
pipeline.drawFrom(source)
.aggregate(aggregate)
.drainTo(sink);
```

Source:

```
Sources.<Key, Record>map("mapname")
```

Aggregate:

```
AggregateOperation1<Entry<Key, Record>, T, Result>=
AggregateOperation
                .withCreate(() -> {
                    Accumulator a = new Accumulator(this);
                    a.initialize();
                    return a;
                }).<Entry<Key, Record>>andAccumulate(
                        (acc, row) -> acc.apply(row))
                .andCombine(
                        (left, right) -> left.combine(right))
                .andFinish(acc -> acc.finish());
```

I'm finding that while executing the pipeline job, the source is reading/writing records in the map:

```
Record.readData
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:191)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:75)
        at Accumulator.apply(Accumulator.java:102)
```

the code in Accumulator.apply (from the "andAccumulate" step) that triggers this looks like

```
private void apply(Entry<IntArr, Record> entry) {
    Record record = entry.getValue();
    ...
}
```

How do i create a Jet map data source that gives the map local entries or values to the AggregateOperation accumulate calls on each node and thread without invoking serialization? Is there something specific i'm doing to make it behave this way?
I believe the cluster is setup to use backup records for aggregation; would that cause this? (I haven't confirmed that this is happening on every record)

EDIT:
This is my current MapConfig:

```
MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig(mapName)
    .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
    .setReadBackupData(true)
    .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
```

As I understand it from http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-in-memory-format InMemoryFormat.OBJECT should instruct the IMap to keep the values in their objective (deserialized) form.

Answer (score 1):

1. A Hazelcast IMap stores the data in serialized form. When you get it from the source, you get a `Map.Entry` instance that will lazily deserialize its key/value when requested. This happens in your `entry.getValue()` call.
2. Your pipeline asks for data aggregation: the output is a single item that reflects all the input data. To reach that result, Jet must send all the partial results to a single member, where it calls your `Accumulator.combine` method to combine them. The ser/de impact of this step should be negligible compared to the one above.

Comment: I recommend that you look at the [docs for in memory format](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-in-memory-format). Currently there is no way to access objects directly through Jet without any deserialization. This may change in the future.

Comment: Additionaly, you can make use of [projections](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#built-in-projections) if your object is large and you only need access to a small part for the aggregation. If you use [`Portable` serialization](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-portable-serialization), you can access the a single attribute without deserializing the whole object.